# Header não consegue encontrar o destino passado

Tags: php, formulário, header

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e a função `header` não consegue localizar o destino passado para a mesma. Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em um determinado formulário, eu passo uma `action` para:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerCategoria">
```

Até aqui está tudo bem, mas o que gostaria é que quando eu chegasse nesse arquivo, eu conseguisse retornar para um arquivo dentro do `admin`.

Estava tentando com o seguinte `header`:

```
header('Location:http://localhost/tecmidiaCor/admin/index.php?pagina=criarPaginas');
```

Nesse caso queria voltar até o arquivo `criarPaginas.php`.

Não coloquei o ponto `PHP` por que em minha `index.php` tenho um script que sempre atribui o conteúdo da variável página.

Comment: Falta um espaço entre `Location: ` e o resto da URL. Além disso, que eu saiba você não pode especificar uma query no campo `Location`. Fora isso, tenha certeza que o caminho existe. E se quiser, pode remover o schema e o domínio, deixando apenas o caminho propriamente dito.

Comment: a questão de espaço não é, o resto eu não entendi o que vc colocou

Comment: por exemplo coloquei o endereço completo do arquivo localmente, mesmo assim não funcionao, header('Location: /Users/andremartins/developer/workspaces/php/tecmidiaCor/admin/index.php');

Comment: Antes de tudo, de uma olhada como funciona o protocolo HTTP, pelo menos na Wikipedia. O caminho físico do arquivo não adianta. O servidor só sabe servir arquivos que estejam na mesma sub-árvore que o `DocumentRoot` (no caso do Apache). Supondo que seu `DocumentRoot` seja `/Users/andremartins/developer/workspaces/php/`, você pode testar com `Location: /tecmidiaCor/admin/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom consegui resolver, o que aparentemente ocorre é que o meu servidor da minha aplicação no caso `APACHE` ele começa a enviar o `response` da `request` solicitada antes de chegar de fato a função `Header()` ou seja envia um corpo na camada de aplicação neste caso utilizando o protocolo `HTTP` isso geralmente ocorre por funções `echo print` ou espaços antes de minhas tags PHP `--  <?php` encontrei uma função cujo no caso o `ob_start` ela resolve o problema por que segura esse conteúdo antes de sua finalização. Em meu código resolvi da seguinte forma, visto que eu estou centralizando minha aplicação no `

```
<body> <?php
if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) {
    require ($_GET["pagina"] . ".php");
} else {
    echo "<h1>Bem vindo ao sistema</h1>";
}
?></body>
```

assim trazendo todas as paginas para o mesmo topo e rodapé, então existia um código `HTML` antes de iniciar este script imagino eu que o mesmo estaria sendo enviado antes da função `HEADER()` propriamente dita, na verdade o ideal seria fazer teste em leitor de `snifer` como `wireshark` então estou supondo que isso aconteceu, no meu caso coloquei o seguinte código antes de tudo em minha `index.php` `<?php ob_start(); ?>` e meu `HEADER` que estava em outro diretório eu apenas coloquei da seguinte forma `header("Location: index.php?pagina=criarPaginas")` que redireciona para outro diretório da minha aplicação, agradeço a todos inclusive ao @Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira